# Как сделать проверку на одних классах без IF?

Tags: php

К примеру есть класс категории и товаров в магазине. И надо вывести товары выбранной категории .
Обычно это все делают `if` проверками , но вот как это сделать без `if`? только классы и объекты, без `if`.

у меня близко нету идей как это возможно реализовать. Можно хоть какой то маленький , самый маленький пример или хотя бы просто на словах... Очень заинтересовала задачка.

Comment: "Обычно это все делают if проверками" -- кто эти все? Где такое написано?

Comment: А switch будет работать?

Comment: @СергейМишин это как то не очень подходит как ответ . :)

Comment: @ВиталийБриль Нет , switch не будет , это тот же if почти . Говорят , чтобы юзали классы и объекты , никаких if быть не должно . Я не понимаю как это ...

Comment: @XXXXXX потому что и вопрос не очень. Ибо выдумки из головы - это такое себе. Ну собссн я пишу в комментариях, а не ответе

Comment: @СергейМишин я как бы дискуссию такого рода не просил :)

Comment: Ну вы так утверждаете, что мне лично интересно кто эти все, и кто вам это сказал. Собственно вопрос конкретно поэтому не ясен, потому что везде сделано по разному. И это реализуется банально маршрутизацией. Потому что всё делается сейчас на cms да фреймворках. А на if'ах как раз никто не делает

Comment: @ВСЕ хватит цепляться к слова, что он там написал, кто ему что сказал! Мне кажется тебе подойдёт через $_GET получать даные

Comment: @ВиталийБриль можно чуть чуть поподробнее, если можно конечно . :)

Comment: Приведите код, где вы получаете товар, а потом через if показываете только выбранную категорию

Comment: Страница с товаром содержит параметры. Предполагаю в параметре передаётся категория, по ней сразу строим запрос на все товары. Не знаю как реализован у вас магазин, покажите код, а то я могу не то подсказать

Comment: @ВиталийБриль Всё, я вас понял , допустим localhost/elektronic. Берём при помощи GET elektronic и делаем Select и там уже Select *from XXXXX table where XXX=elektronic . Ну крч как то так , верно понимаю ?

Comment: да верно. Но одна if проверка все-таки будет, проверка на пустоту (но это уже на стороне фронта)

Comment: @ВиталийБриль А вот если бы вы проектировали магазин (совсем простой), то какие классы у вас были бы ? 
Я заюзал класс Базы данных . Товара . Категории

Comment: у меня бы был класс маршрутизации, как ранее говорил @СергейМишин

Comment: @ВиталийБриль Ну вот на laravel уже писал такое , но на простом php чет понятие не имею как и что с этим классом ...

Comment: Думаю статья поможет: https://qna.habr.com/q/178365

Comment: @ВиталийБриль ойййй мама .... ладно , буду пытаться разобраться ... чет вообще не понял там нечего

Comment: Спасибо большое )

Answer (score 0):

Вам подойдёт через $_GET получать данные:

Допустим перешли по ссылке: `localhost/?category=elektronic`.

Делаем запрос в бд `SELECT * FROM 'table'.table WHERE category=$_GET['category']`.

Это если прям сильно упрощенно, без соблюдения безопасности